# Pandas multi-index data access

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a multi-index dataframe like this:

```
       TC_name  Year
id id2              
1  1      RITA  2020
   2      RITA  2020
2  1       IDA  2020
   2       IDA  2020
   3       IDA  2020
   4       IDA  2021
3  1      RITA  2021
   2      RITA  2021
   3      RITA  2021
```

Now, I want to access the first line for each ‘id’ group, i.e. (1,1) = RITA2020, (2,1) = IDA2020, (3,1) = RITA2021...and use them to form a new dataframe.

However, when I try `df.loc[:,1]`, it does not work. I tried `df.loc[1]`, `df.loc[2]` and it gives me the right group, but it seems that the 'id2' `index` can not work well.

So what should I do next to get access to the data I want?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming OP wants to create a dataframe based on the first element of each group, one can use [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html). As OP wants the first index, `id`, one should be `level=0`. Finally, considering that OP wants the first element for each group, then one needs to pass [`.first()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html)

```
df2 = df.groupby(level=0).first()

[Out]:
   TC_name  Year
id              
1     RITA  2020
2      IDA  2020
3     RITA  2021
```